# Setting Print title columns as dynamic ranges

Tags: excel, vba

I have 100s of pages of data that I need to print and I want to have a header and a side column on every Page that is printed.

I can do this manually by using the dynamic range that I have created but I have to manually enter the name of the range into the page layout settings. I also tried to use a macro to do this using my dynamic ranges but I get an error message when I run the following script;

```
Sheets("1. Paste Raw Data").Select
ActiveSheet.PageSetup.PrintTitleColumns = Sheets("1. Paste Raw Data").Range("Print_Side")
ActiveSheet.PageSetup.PrintTitleRows = Sheets("1. Paste Raw Data").Range("Print_Header")
```

I have also tried to use the range that is defined by excel (named Print_Titles) to change these settings when the pages are printed but it will not allow me to enter more than one dynamic range. Print_Titles is currently defined like this in name manager;

```
='1. Paste Raw Data'!$B:$B,'1. Paste Raw Data'!$4:$6
```

Is there a way of using the two dynamic ranges in to define the titles for the rows and the columns?

Comment: Is your "dynamic range" a named range?  If not, how did you make it dynamic?

Comment: yes, it is a named range using the offset function. I know it is working because I can get it to do what I want when I manually enter the named ranges into the page formatting window, I just dont want to have to do that everytime I print the document.

Answer (score 0):

I am afraid what you are trying to do, is not accepted by Excel...

It allows setting of `PrintTitleRows` like **Rows**, not like a range (like your dynamic range). Excel allows setting only of the `ROWS`to be repeated. In case of using a range (manually selected), Excel extends the range, to include full rows. In terms of range, it accepts only a range of rows.

If you insist to use your dynamic range you can use:

```
ActiveSheet.PageSetup.PrintTitleRows = _
    ActiveSheet.Rows(Names("Print_Header").RefersToRange.Row).Address
```

but it would be like you scratch your left side of your head using the right arm...

You can also proceed similarly for `PrintTitleColumns`, but you will obtain the same result just using of:

```
ActiveSheet.PageSetup.PrintTitleColumns = "$A:$A"
```

Even you would manually try setting of those parameters, you would observe that Excel does not allow selecting of ranges. It extends the selection to the whole row(s) or column(s) according to the setting specificity.